# Monstera Adensonii (vining) Cuttings not growing and curled leaves after 3 months

Tags: houseplants, propagation, cuttings, water, monstera

[image: monstera w roots in water]

I've had 3 monstera aderisoni leaf cuttings from etsy since the end of August. They shipped from Florida. All are still alive but none have tried to grow a new leaf and all look a bit curled up. I'd love some advice. Below is a leaf i've had in water since October. I change the water every few days. It gets a bit of afternoon sun from a far every day.  I have a bright home with lots of light in Colorado.

Here's another one in soil see how its curled up and has a bit of brown on it? [image: monstera leaf in water]

[image: monstera in soil]

The last picture is the most bizarre. This leaf totally turned brown. It was in soil. I pulled it out of the pot (same pot pictured above) to throw it away and saw roots and a tiny bit of green at the base of the stem so being a scientist a plant experiment ensued. In a jar I can see roots. And it is growing a new leaf - and quickly! But again after 3 months i'd expect more than a single leaf on the three cuttings. [image]

**The Backstory**

When I got all three cuttings in the mail I put them in water immediately. When they started to grow roots I moved them to soil in the pot pictured in this post.

When I moved them to soil they started to get curled up and I got nervous id lose all three so one went back into water in October (pictured above) so I could watch it grow roots. In late October the one leaf (of two in the soil) totally turned brown. Maybe over over watered? it looked dead. That is the one that i moved into the glass jar that is now sprouting a new leaf.

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong with these beautiful cuttings?

---

UPDATE: i'm going to try boiled (and cooled) de-chlorinated water  as suggested below and more hours of brighter light! i'll report back on what i find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

- change the water more often, use de chlorinated water if available
- provide more light
- when there are roots, take a straight edge razor and cut the tip off, this will cause more roots to grow

Comment: thank you @kevinsky ! i didn't know that you could trim roots. and hadn't considered water without chlorine. i'll try it. do you happen to know how much direct light an adensonii needs? this is what i've been torn about as i read deliciousa can handle direct light but not adensonii but then again you read all sorts of things online. i have them in bright light right now by a west facing sliding glass door but am worried about direct hot sun (colorado sun). ive played with putting them far enough away that they get only an hour of afternoon sun and also moving them closer to the large window.

Comment: @LeahWasser Indirect light is recommended, morning sun is rarely too hot, or even a northern exposure that is unobstructed.  Also, this plant does better at 70 Deg F and up. Some houses only heat to 68 Deg F.  Cool temperatures slow growth.  Could this be a factor?