# Variegated monstera cutting propagation

Tags: houseplants, indoors, propagation, cuttings, monstera

I have a variegated *Monstera* cutting (shown below). I want to promote root growth so it can be potted. I live in Australia, currently going into spring.

[image]

The cutting was left out for a day and a half so the node could callus over, and now it's sitting in a jar of rain water in a room with bright indirect sunlight.

[I've read](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55810/) that changing the water frequently is important.

**Are there any other tips / techniques to promote root growth?**

Comment: Gardening Australia (TV) has just featured this.